# Tensorflow Keras Embedding Layer Error: Layer weight shape not compatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Can anyone recommend the best path for me to fix this type of error?  I can't figure out what I've done wrong with my dimensions.  I have a pretrained embedding that originates in a Word2Vec gensim model, which I want to use to initialize the CNN with.  Sorry for the relatively simple question, but very new to both Keras and Tensorflow

```
#CNN architecture

num_classes = num_labels

#Training params
batch_size = 8 
num_epochs = 25

#Model parameters
num_filters = 64  
weight_decay = 1e-4
kernel_size = 7 #this is the size of the window during convolution...making match the window size in Word2Vec...unsure if needed

print("training CNN ...")

model = Sequential()

#------------------------
FIXED_LENGTH=embedding_matrix.shape[1]
#------------------------

print('Vocab size:', vocab_size)
print('Output_Dim size:', w2v.vector_size)
print('Weights:', pd.Series([embedding_matrix]).shape)
print('Weights underlying shape:', embedding_matrix.shape)
print("Input Length:", FIXED_LENGTH)

#Model add word2vec embedding

model.add(Embedding(vocab_size+1, 
                      output_dim=w2v.vector_size, 
                      weights=[embedding_matrix], 
                      input_length=FIXED_LENGTH, 
                      trainable=False))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))  #multi-label (k-hot encoding)

adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

#define callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]

print('Batch size:', batch_size)
print('Num of Epochs:', num_epochs)
print('X Train Size:', x_train_pad.shape)
print('Y Train Size:', y_train.shape)

hist = model.fit(x_train_pad, 
                 y_train, 
                 batch_size=batch_size, 
                 epochs=num_epochs, 
                 callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                 validation_split=0.1, 
                 shuffle=True, 
                 verbose=2)
```

Output is:

```
training CNN ...
Vocab size: 32186
Output_Dim size: 100
Weights: (1,)
Weights underlying shape: (32186, 100)
Input Length: 100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-326-36db7b551866> in <module>()
     31                       weights=[embedding_matrix],
     32                       input_length=FIXED_LENGTH,
---> 33                       trainable=False))
     34 model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same'))
     35 model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))

c:\users\tt\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

c:\users\tt\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    176           # and create the node connecting the current layer
    177           # to the input layer we just created.
--> 178           layer(x)
    179           set_inputs = True
    180 

c:\users\tt\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    815           # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been
    816           # overridden).
--> 817           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    818           cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
    819 

c:\users\tt\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   2146     # Optionally load weight values specified at layer instantiation.
   2147     if getattr(self, '_initial_weights', None) is not None:
-> 2148       self.set_weights(self._initial_weights)
   2149       self._initial_weights = None
   2150 

c:\users\tt\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1334         raise ValueError('Layer weight shape ' + str(ref_shape) +
   1335                          ' not compatible with '
-> 1336                          'provided weight shape ' + str(w.shape))
   1337       weight_value_tuples.append((p, w))
   1338     backend.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)

ValueError: Layer weight shape (32187, 100) not compatible with provided weight shape (32186, 100)
```

Comment: Where did you get your w2v weights? How are you preprocessing your data? Is there a provided tokenizer or at least word index to go with the w2v weights? Btw, `input_length` is not the vocabulary size, it's the length of the sequences you will give the model. Because your current model architecture can handle any length, you probably shouldn't bother trying to set it.

Comment: W2V weights come from a gensim model I built and used nltk.word_tokenize to initialize and then trained a W2V to 100D.  Thanks for the tip on input_length.  I have been massively confused about the dimensions for the CNN pipeline.  The reason is because all the examples already had preprocessing finished and dimensions were all set in the sample files.  Then I applied real world and it got nasty fast.  Appreciate you looking at it.  Dimensions of gensim model was 32186x100.  I'll try to remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Also, if you know any good examples I'm happy to read other code.  Couldn't find anything outside already preprocessed examples on Github to learn from.

Comment: Adding +1 to vocab_size AND removing input_length yields:

InvalidArgumentError:  indices[3,91] = 60729 is not in [0, 32186)
  [[node sequential_35/embedding_43/embedding_lookup (defined at c:\users\ttrusse\anaconda3b\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_12609]

Function call stack:
distributed_function

Comment: I've only ever used my own embeddings in pure Keras, so I'm not sure how best to use nltk/gensim. I'd recommend reading more about how text preprocessing in general works, so that you can develop an understanding of what numbers have to match what other numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was the encoded sentences contains values higher than were encoded in the lexicon build stage.  There should be an index in your lexicon for every value of your training and test set.  If not, you have to clean the sentences before sending them to the CNN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `vocab_size+1` argument in the Embedded layer to `vocab_size`. I think its the +1 that is causing problem

Comment: ValueError: Layer weight shape (32187, 100) not compatible with provided weight shape (32186, 100)